# barplot, average discrete numbers (10 classes septerated by 2 years and orderd by 4 groups)

Tags: r, ggplot2

my question is: How can i get a barplotgraph for each ´grad´ (4 groups) of the average discrete numbers per ´BHD Klasse´ (10 classes) separated according to the years ´jahr´( 2 different years), thanks in advance –

```
BHD Klasse     jahr      grad
1              2020      schwach
2              2020      stark
3              2020      wenig
4              2011      kein
.              .         .
.              .         .
.              .         .
10             2011      schwach
```

was gonna use this code but its not working as i want it:

```
ggplot()+ geom_histogram(data=bhdklass,aes(x = bhdklasse, fill=jahr))+
  facetwrap(~grad)
```

Would be awesome to hear from you. Elza

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the average discrete number per `BHD Klasse`"?  Do you want to know how many different `BHD Klasse` values occur for each group-year?

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

Try this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data=bhdklass,aes(x = bhdklasse, fill = as.factor(jahr)))+
  facet_wrap(~grad) +
  labs(fill = "jahr")
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Please note: we don't have your data. But you can use `facet_wrap` to plot multiple facet per jahr for example like this:

```
bhdklass <- data.frame(bhdklasse = c(1,2,3,4),
                   jahr = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2011),
                   grad = c("schwach", "stark", "wenig", "kein"))

  library(tidyverse)
  ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(data=bhdklass,aes(x = bhdklasse, fill = grad))+
    facet_wrap(~jahr) +
    theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Please remind the data looks weird because of fewer elements.

Comment: yes thanks but it will only gimmi the sum of bhd klasse. What i would need is the mean for each "bhd klasse " for the 2 years (2011 and 2020) seperated. so i swaped the "jahr " und "grad" in your code,  but it gives me the error that i have different row numbers for the 2 yerars. which is correct but since i wanne use the mean it shouldnt matter right?

Comment: @Else, Added code!

Comment: Hey thanks. But it still gives me an error since i dont have 4 but 10 klasses. and R doesnt like it. But i just did it without the data.frame set up. and it kinda worked. But i still have the absolute values. What i need are the relative ( Mean) values. Because i also have have different sample sizes in each"grad" - so the "kein" has 22, "wenig" has 24, "schwach" has 17 and "stark"has 74. so the values in the graph i somehow need to divide through the specific number of sample size right? i have no idea, Thanks in advance